# Redirection on tomcat9

Tags: tomcat, redirect

I have an application published on the web (https://xxxxx:port/admin/app) and i would like to redirect to a error page when the user use 
https://xxxxx:port/admin or block the access to this page.

Thank you

Comment: for your application you might have servlets to handle the URLs, what kind of application you have please be more specific and add those details in your question

Comment: I have an oracle apex application. The problem that the url for the developer is http://ip:port/apex and for the users is http://ip:port/apex/myapps. The ip is public so i want to restrict the public users the access to the developer page